# Set value to button in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewrow, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I set value to button in datagridview in formload by the code below:

```
        DataGridViewButtonColumn btnDelete = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

        btnDeleteText = "Delete";
        btnDelete.HeaderText = "Delete";
        btnDelete.DataPropertyName = "btnDelete";
        btnDelete.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

        dgvPur.Columns.Insert(0,btnDelete);
```

But after running completed the button text is empty.

Comment: Have you checked the width and height of the grid cells?

Comment: Sorry !! When the form loaded i didn't see the button text but after i added a row I see the button text !! It was my mistake !!

Comment: If this is fixed then answer your own question or marked as closed. Haha one can easily solve a problem by just playing with it and testing various types of conditions.

Comment: yeah !! and spending 1:30 hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy !! just add a new row you will see delete text on a button.